# Flickity carousel images squashed together

Tags: carousel, flickity

I am using to this slider on my website: http://flickity.metafizzy.co

The images load in squashed, but on refresh it sometimes appear as it should. I have decreased the images size, because I thought perhaps it was a loading issue, but that didn't help. I then added imagesLoaded, and that also did nothing.

I've attached a screenshot of how the images load. thanks!

[image: http://imgur.com/OA66JK2]

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are using `flickity.pkgd.js` and not just `flickity.js`.

Check that your option is set correctly

```
// with jQuery
$('.gallery').flickity({
  imagesLoaded: true
});
```

-

```
// or with vanilla JS
new Flickity( '.gallery', {
  imagesLoaded: true
});
```

-

```
<!-- or in HTML -->
<div class="gallery js-flickity" data-flickity-options='{ "imagesLoaded": true }'></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work over here :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503849/flickity-wont-initialize-properly-unless-resizing-window-rails-6